# Scrapy Craigslist script

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy, craigslist

I want to create a Scrapy script to scrape all of the results for computer gigs in any craigslist subdomain: 
for example here: http://losangeles.craigslist.org/search/cpg/
This query returns a list of many articles and I've tried to scrape the title and href of each of this results (not only the ones on the first page) to no avail using CrawlSpider and linkExtractor, but the Script returns nothing.
I'll paste my script here, thanks

```
    import scrapy
    from scrapy.spiders import Rule,CrawlSpider
    from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

    class CraigspiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
        name = "CraigSpider"
        allowed_domains = ["http://losangeles.craigslist.org"]
        start_urls = (
                    'http://losangeles.craigslist.org/search/cpg/',
        )

        rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="button next"]',)), callback="parse_page", follow= True),)

        def parse_page(self, response):
            items = response.selector.xpath("//p[@class='row']")
        for i in items:
            link = i.xpath("./span[@class='txt']/span[@class='pl']/a/@href").extract()
            title = i.xpath("./span[@class='txt']/span[@class='pl']/a/span[@id='titletextonly']/text()").extract()
            print link,title
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you pasted, `parse_page`:

1. does not return/yield anything, and
2. only contains one line: "items = response.selector..."

The reason for #2 above is that the `for` loop is not properly indented.

Try to indent the `for` loop:

```
class CraigspiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "CraigSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["http://losangeles.craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ('http://losangeles.craigslist.org/search/cpg/',)

    rules = (Rule(
        LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="button next"]',)),
        callback="parse_page", follow= True))

    def parse_page(self, response):
        items = response.selector.xpath("//p[@class='row']")

        for i in items:
            link = i.xpath("./span[@class='txt']/span[@class='pl']/a/@href").extract()
            title = i.xpath("./span[@class='txt']/span[@class='pl']/a/span[@id='titletextonly']/text()").extract()
            print link, title
            yield dict(link=link, title=title)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helped me shed some light on the problem. I have a working version now on my github account i'll edit my question later to include the link to my repo. Thanks! have a great day

Comment: @ErnestoPM: Feel free to accept this answer and upvote if you liked it very much.